# Haproxy - Browser communication, request are looping

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, haproxy

I have a log collection service on my server which is using haproxy. All request coming from outside are served thru haproxy.
[image]

When I call the log collection service from curl/postman, log collection for all services happens at backend and a zip is downloaded on the client machine.

This happens fine when using curl/postman even for 30 GB file. Log collection can take 15-20 minutes in this case.

But when using browser, the operation goes in looping behavior, i.e. haproxy keeps getting new requests from the client and old ones have haproxy_termination_state: CD. Though network tab doesn't show any new request going to the server and stays in Pending state forever.
[image]

```json
{
  "app": "haproxy",
  "content_type": "-",
  "dst_connect_time": "2",
  "dst_ip": "x.x.x.32",
  "dst_port": "8090",
  "dst_response_time": "1126057",
  "duration": "1126059",
  "haproxy_backend": "x_read",
  "haproxy_termination_state": "CD",
  "host": "x",
  "http_status": "200",
  "msg": "200 GET /x/api/v1/logs?minTime=2023-10-03T03:30:03.634Z&maxTime=2023-10-10T03:30:03.634Z HTTP/1.1",
  "request_bytes": "1094",
  "response_bytes": "4083",
  "src_ip": "x.x.x.53",
  "src_port": "49605",
  "timestamp": "2023-10-10T03:48:55Z",
  "user_agent": "like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
```

As curl and postman are working fine, it seems to be a browser specific issue. I have checked space on the system (which is fine), Download settings on the Chrome (which seem fine too).

Is there any scenario when haproxy retries request internally or browser sends request again without showing on network tab?

It works fine in my environment even if request has to wait for more than 5 minutes. But issue happens in customer's env.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any scenario when haproxy retries request internally or browser sends request again without showing on network tab?

Yes. Chrome, Firefox and Edge all have a 5 minute timeout for http requests.

> Log collection can take 15-20 minutes in this case.

Then you can't make a synchronous reuest from a browser for the logs. You'll need to use comet or web sockets (and I would suggest these implement a flagging system with redirect to the content rather than serving the content directly).

Comment: In my env, even if response is not received for 8-9 minutes, I don't see looping behaviour. It is specific to a customer's env. Where settings are almost similar. I added the image in the question.

Comment: I checked `network.http.response.timeout` in my browser and it was set to 300. Not sure if this is the coorect setting I am checking. But if it is, it did not cause the request to fail/loop.